# Using Hex Codes for Colours in ACM Graphics API

Tags: java, colors, acm-java-libraries

I am writing a simple program using the **ACM Graphics API**, and am trying to use the `setColor()` method to set the color of a turtle. How do I have it use a hex code rather than a `Color.COLOR` mode because that does not have my color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
gObject.setColor(Color.decode("0x054628")); // turtle green
```